# How to sync all the changes made to gradle files between projects android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

So when I make any changes to `build.gradle app module` or `build.gradle project` file in Android Studio, I then have to do a project syncing. Which is successful. But when I open or create another project(even after closing Android Studio and running it again), the changes made to the `build.gradle` files are not applied in the new project. So if I implement a new library in one of my projects and sync it, I still have to implement and sync that library again in every other project I might need. Is there a way to make changes once, and then have it in every other project without syncing it again ? Isn't project syncing supposed to do the job ?
I`m running Android Studio 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't project syncing supposed to do the job ?

No. `Sync Project with Gradle Files` only syncs the current project with the gradle files in that project's folder.